# How to add approval process after customer registration?

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account, customer-registration

How to add approval process after customer registration in Magento 2?

Whenever customer register, after that it should be go for the approval and Magento admin can approve or reject the account.

Only after the approval from admin, customer can log-in.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-customer-approval

Comment: You need to buy a plug in. Magento doesn't come with that feature.

Comment: you can purchase mageants [magento 2 customer approval](https://www.mageants.com/customer-approval-for-magento-2.html) extension it will help to solve